# VSO scope in Azure AD identity provider

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-bot-service, microsoft-identity-platform

I am building a bot which will be calling Azure DevOps to update the work item (scope required - vso.work_write [Update Work item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) ). For this I want to have the user authenticate itself using OAuth. Following [Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv2%2Ccsharp) doc I created the bot channel registration followed by identity provider and then registering the identity provider in my bot. Now when I go to my identity provider under API permission -> Add a permission -> Azure Devops all I see is a "user_impersonation" permission whereas my requirement is to add a vso.work_write permission to modify ado work items.

[image]

How can I add a vso.work_write permission to my identity provider so that my bot picks up the required scope while building the token ? Or is there any method to manually enter the scope in the bot code ?

**Note** :- I tried giving "user_impersonation" scope and generating the token with that scope but I still get a 401.

**Edit 1** :-
I am able to generate a jwt token but using that token I am not able to hit ado endpoint that's why I am suspecting it to be a scope issue only.

Comment: Hey @KevinLu-MSFT I actually followed the step both in the answer and the other ticket you have mentioned but it didn't help. As a workaround I created a Generic OAuth provider in bot service with endpoint of token url, refresh url pointing to my localhost, where a controller is built to handle this requests.

Comment: Thanks for your update. You could add an answer to share you method and Accept the answer. This will be helpful other members. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following steps:

1. You could use the URL: `https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect` to create an App registration.
2. Grant the **user_impersonation** to the APP and generate the secret.
3. Go to **Bot service -> Settings -> OAuth Connection Settings -> Add Setting**

Select the **Azure Active Directory** and input the info.

[image]

[Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#openid-connect-scopes): openid, email, profile, and offline_access. You could select openid

Based on your description, the vso.work_write scope exists in the [Outh Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops) and PAT ([Personal Access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page)).

You can also refer to [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops) to generate the Azure Devops outh token and use it in the Bot Service settings.

Here is [a ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57873082/bot-framework-authentication-issues-getting-401) with the similar issue, you could refer to it.